How can I write a subclass of scipy.stats.rv_continuous with variable number of shape parameters or a list of numbers as a shape parameter?
I need to implement a 1D continuous random variable/distribution, but the shape depends on a "list" of integers that can have different lengths. I am able to create and use subclasses of rv_continuous that have a fixed number of shape parameters, but so far I could not make it work with variable numbers.
I would really like to use SciPy's rv_continuous as base, since it gives me a lot of useful functionality for free.
I tried something like this:
class Cee(rv_continuous):
    """A random variable representing the maximum of multiple chi distributions.

    Each :any:`chi <scipy.stats.chi>` disitribution can have a different ``df``.

    .. note::
        You probably do not need to use this class directly. Instead work with
        the instance :data:`cee`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    k : list of int or int
        List of degrees of freedom of the chi-distirbuted variables to take the
        maximum of.

    """

    def _cdf(self, x: ArrayLike, k: ArrayLike) -> ArrayLike:
        k = np.atleast_1d(k)
        p = [chi.cdf(x, df=n) for n in k]
        return np.prod(p, axis=0)

#: Use this instance of :class:`Cee`
cee = Cee(name="cee", a=0)

But when I try to use this e.g. with cee(k=[1,2,3]).pdf(0.5) it does not return a single number, but three, because SciPy's internal argument handling assumes that I want three different Cees with different single integers as the shape parameter.
Is there any way I can tell rv_continuous that k should be a 1D object for a single random variable?

No, but see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/21339. I will write this up as an answer in a bit.

There is not a native way to do this; the existing infrastructure supports neither a) a variable number of separate shape parameters or b) to use a "1D object for a single random variable". The reason is that the built-in methods for parsing arguments passed to other methods weren't written with a variable number of shape parameters in mind, and using a "1D object for a single random variable" breaks normal broadcasting rules.
The trick is to replace the built-in methods that parse the arguments. For example, in gh-21339 (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/21339), I want the methods to accept a single argument p, which contains a variable number of shape parameters along the last axis, and I return it as a tuple of separate shape parameters that the infrastructure understands.
# The _parse_args methods don't work with vector-valued shape parameters, so we rewrite
# them. Note that `p` is accepted as an array with the index `i` of `p_i` corresponding
# with the last axis; we return it as a tuple (p_1, p_2, ..., p_n) so that it looks
# like `n` scalar (or arrays of scalar-valued) shape parameters to the infrastructure.

def _parse_args_rvs(self, p, loc=0, size=None):
    return tuple(np.moveaxis(p, -1, 0)), loc, 1.0, size

def _parse_args_stats(self, p, loc=0, moments='mv'):
    return tuple(np.moveaxis(p, -1, 0)), loc, 1.0, moments

def _parse_args(self, p, loc=0):
    return tuple(np.moveaxis(p, -1, 0)), loc, 1.0

Unfortunately, these methods are bound to the object in a non-standard way, so we can't just override them. We have to bind them manually.
# The infrastructure manually binds these methods to the instance, so
# we can only override them by manually binding them, too.
_pb_obj, _pb_cls = poisson_binom, poisson_binom_gen  # shorter names (for PEP8)
poisson_binom._parse_args_rvs = _parse_args_rvs.__get__(_pb_obj, _pb_cls)
poisson_binom._parse_args_stats = _parse_args_stats.__get__(_pb_obj, _pb_cls)
poisson_binom._parse_args = _parse_args.__get__(_pb_obj, _pb_cls)

You can see that the same sort of thing needs to happen for frozen instances of the distribution.
Besides that, there were only a few tweaks I had to make to the infrastructure itself.

There was a failure because in _construct_doc it tries to do vals = ', '.join(f'{val:.3g}' for val in shapes_vals), but val can now be an array.
There were some issues because some methods call the public versions of other methods, which effectively runs the _parse_args... function multiple times. This breaks things, so I had to tweak them to call the private version of the function (e.g. _ppf instead of ppf). That's probably how it should have been anyway so that input validation is not repeated unnecessarily.

But besides that, it basically "just works" after you override those _parse_args... methods. The distributions have an attribute numargs that you might want to set based on the number of arguments, but it doesn't seem to affect much.

Depending on your use case, there is a totally different approach that  is even less invasive. You could write a class that is not itself a subclass of rv_continuous; instead, a method of your class (e.g. __init__) defines an rv_continuous subclass with a fixed number of parameters - but that the fixed number is chosen based on the arguments the method receives. You'd instantiate that subclass of rv_continuous and store it as an attribute. Then you could make short wrappers of all the public methods you want, and those would just call the corresponding methods of that distribution attribute and return the result. The advantage is that there is less hackery, but the disadvantage is that the distribution is not actually a subclass of rv_continuous.

Thanks, I was trying to mess with the argument parsing, but did not manage to get it to work. I was trying to let it accept an arbitrary number of keyword arguments, and turn them into the positional arguments that the rest of the class seems to expect. Your method of turning a single parameter into multiple looks a bit neater.
In the mean time I managed to work around the issue by wrapping my variable length arguments in a class, that is not automatically convertible to a numpy array. I will post this as a separate potential solution here.

Looks like there is no "standard" way of doing this. Matt Haberland's way is one possible solution, but in the mean time I worked around this problem in a different way.
Since SciPy tries to turn the shape arguments into NumPy arrays and then treats every element of the array as a separate requested shape parameter, I simply wrapped my variable length parameter into a class that cannot get converted to an array automatically. In this case NumPy will just create an array of these objects, and I deal with the objects in my code:
class DF:
    """Helper class to get around limitations of `rv_continuous`.

    This class represents the shape parameter for the :class:`Cee` and
    :class:`Cee2` distributions.

    Parameters
    ----------

    *args : tuple of int
        The `df` for each chi(2) distribution

    """

    def __init__(self, *args: tuple[int]) -> None:
        self.df = args

    def __gt__(self, other: Any) -> bool:
        return True



class Cee(rv_continuous):
    """A random variable representing the maximum of multiple chi distributions.

    Each :any:`chi <scipy.stats.chi>` disitribution can have a different ``df``. If
    all ``df`` are equal to 1, this is identical to the :class:`Bee`
    distribution with ``df = len(k)``.

    .. note::
        You probably do not need to use this class directly. Instead work with
        the instance :data:`cee`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    k : DF or Iterable of DF
        Special class to pass variable length list of degrees of freedom of the
        chi-distirbuted variables to take the maximum of.

    Examples
    --------

    >>> cee(k=DF(1,2,3)).pdf(1)
    0.2501359390297275

    """

    def _cdf(self, x: NDArray[Any], k: Iterable[DF]) -> NDArray[Any]:
        # Translate each DF object into df tuple
        dof = [_k.df for _k in k]
        # Calculate and return cdf for each
        return np.array([np.prod([chi.cdf(x, df=n) for n in _k], axis=0) for _k in dof])

The __gt__ method is necessary so these objects will pass the internal quality check for the shape parameters.
I like this method, because it requires the minimum amount of messing with the internals of the rv_continuous class. Of course at the cost of having to use this wrapper class to specify shape arguments.
